# Ternary operator within awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to create an awk script to read data from a txt file and create an output script. Script is printing unnecessary information on line 1 and 3. Is it possible to create the output ?

`awk -F'[",]+' '{print "echo line " (NF>7 ? $(NF-2) " commands1 " $(NF-1) " " $2 " object " $3" object " $4 " object " $5 " object ": $(NF-2) " commands1 " $(NF-1) " " $2 " object " $3" object ") "commands2"""}' test.txt`

**test.txt**

```
"b","1","program"
"c","a","d","b","2","program"
"a","3","program"
"c","a","4","program"
"a","b","5","program"
```

**Output:**

```
echo line 1 commands1 program b object 1 object commands2
echo line 2 commands1 program c object a object d object b object commands2
echo line 3 commands1 program a object 3 object commands2
echo line 4 commands1 program c object a object commands2
echo line 5 commands1 program a object b object commands2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
echo line 1 commands1 program b object commands2
echo line 2 commands1 program c object a object d object b object commands2
echo line 3 commands1 program a object commands2
echo line 4 commands1 program c object a object commands2
echo line 5 commands1 program a object b object commands2
```

Comment: It would be simpler if you used the ternary just for fields after `$3`, since that's the only part that differs between the two cases.

Comment: Why do you expect that output? Shouldn't `$3` be after `object` on lines 1 and 3?

Comment: "1 object" and "3 object" are unnecessary information.

Comment: You have `object " $3" object` in the `NF<=7` case. If `$3` is unnecessary, don't print it.

Comment: Actually I have three cases here not two.

Comment: I only see one ternary, how can there be 3 cases?

Comment: I also tried without `object $3 object` If I remove `object $3 object`, I have missing fields on line 4 and line 5

Comment: You only have 2 cases: `NF > 7` and `NF <= 7`. So all rows with less than 7 fields will print `object $3 object`

Comment: That's true `NF > 7` and `NF <=7` but the outputs are not same for line 1,3 and line 4,5. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sure it is. On line 1 `$3 == 1`, on line 4 `$3 == a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your subject line is talking about ternary operators, but here's one way to do what you appear to be trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[\",]+" }
{
    printf "echo line %d commands1 %s", $(NF-2), $(NF-1)
    for (i=2; i<(NF-2); i++) {
        printf " %s object", $i
    }
    print " commands2"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
echo line 1 commands1 program b object commands2
echo line 2 commands1 program c object a object d object b object commands2
echo line 3 commands1 program a object commands2
echo line 4 commands1 program c object a object commands2
echo line 5 commands1 program a object b object commands2
```